# I am having trouble discretizising this system with matrices A, B, C and D.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrices A, B, C and D are given by

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-2&-2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}4&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Sampling time $T=\frac\pi2$

I know that $J=\begin{bmatrix}-1+i&0\\0&-1-i \end{bmatrix}$ which gives me $e^{Jt}$. Which will help me in calculating $e^{At}=Qe^{Jt}Q^-1$

I have found Q to be $Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1+i&-1-i\end{bmatrix}$, which also gives me the solution for $Q^-1$,  but I am wondering if this is wrong, because I am not able to find the correct discretized form when doing the calculations.

Have I missed some steps? Or are any of my steps wrong?

Comment: Are you using the formulas $A_d=e^{AT}$, $B_d=\int_{0}^{T}e^{As}dsB $ ? Verify if AQ=QJ

Comment: Yes I am, Q is the eigenvectors, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}-1-i&-1+i\\ 2&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1+i&0\\ 0&-1-i\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-1-i&-1+i\\ 2&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\end{equation}

To find the first eigenvector (the first column of $Q$), solve the following equation:
$$(A-\lambda_1I)v=0,$$
where $\lambda_1$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. This equation has infinitely many solutions, all of them being of the form
$$v = \alpha\begin{bmatrix}-1-i\\ 2\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar.

The second eigenvector is found in a similar way.

Comment: How did you arrive to this solution? How did you find Q?

Comment: See my new answer